# Best way to share python code across various services?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, databricks, python-wheel

I write python code in many areas i.e. databricks notebooks, locally, in AWS lambdas, and I'd like an easy way to share code amongst all those services. I don't want to publish our code to any kind of public pypi repository or anything.

The best idea I can think of is packaging shared code into wheel files and uploading to S3. I could then configure my S3 bucket with a pypi server and use pip install to run the code on databricks. Maybe something similar in lambdas?

Does anyone have a better idea? I feel like wheels is a little overkill since I have to define so many things (version numbers, operating systems, etc.). I don't need this to be public it could just be an internally managed system

Answer (score 2):

You could use pip, git(hub) and tags to share packages privately amongst your team. Also, I agree that you shouln't use wheels. It is 'overkill.' Also, this link may help you: http://jtushman.github.io/blog/2013/06/17/sharing-code-across-applications-with-python/#2